# QMOT | Orbital mixing in methyl

Tags: organic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

The following picture is from E. V. Anslyn *Physical Organic Chemistry* and shows constructing of MO of methyl using QMOT. MOs $\textbf{E'}$ and $\textbf{D'}$ are formed by mixing $\textbf{D}$ and $\textbf{E}$. I can't quite imagine how the mixing goes here.

[image: Walsh diagram for for CH_\sub{3}]

Comment: Can you imagine the mixing of _s_ and _p_ atomic orbitals into _sp_? It's pretty much the same.

Comment: Yes thank you, that would illustrate the polarized p lobes, right? But in the mixing that leads to E', the 3 1s obitals meet out of phase. Why the resulting orbitals have these 3 1s orbital in "brown phase" and are not cancelled?